# dotnet pack or nuget pack on gitlab CI

Tags: .net-core, nuget, gitlab-ci

I'm using GitLab and I need to create a `.gitlab-ci.yml` script to run the Continuous Integration pipeline for a project that generates a nuGet package.

I am having serious issues finding reliable documentation to answer this:

Should I use `dotnet pack` or `nuget pack`?

nuget.exe is not available as a command unless my CI script downloads it (I am using GitLab so I would have to add something on `.gitlab-ci.yml` to do so) . My understanding was that `dotnet` implicitly uses nuget so no need to use directly nuget.

The problem with dotnet pack command is that I cannot reference the nuspec file, it is simply ignored.

I've tried with

```
dotnet pack 'MyProject.Nuget/MyProject.Nuget.csproj' /p:NuspecFile='MyProject.Nuget/MyProject.NuGet.nuspec' /p:PackageVersion=$VERSION --output nupkgs
```

Any reliable documentation on what's the right approach for the latest version (`dotnet --version` is 2.1.401) would be much appreciated as I am unable to create valid nuGet packages that contains multiple dll.

**UPDATE**:
The alternative is:

```
nuget pack ./*NuGet/*.nuspec -Version $VERSION -OutputDirectory pepe -Prop Configuration=Release -NoDefaultExcludes -Verbosity detailed
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I successfully build now nuGet packages from CI/CD at GitLab for my dotnet core applications.

Things to keep into consideration:

- The paths are important: My nuspec had paths with the `\` windows-style. I needed to change them to linux-style `/`. 
  Make sure your file src section are referencing dll and pdb that exist at the specified paths or you will get an exception when creating the nuget because it won't find anything. So my nuspec now looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>ToolBelt.Application</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>TUI</authors>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Shared Contracts and Model for the Application layer</description>
    <projectUrl>https://gitlab.tuiwestern.eu/SalesDistribution/_common-packages/ToolBelt.Application</projectUrl>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="bin/*/netstandard2.0/ToolBelt.Application.Model.dll" target="lib/netstandard2.0" />
    <file src="bin/*/netstandard2.0/ToolBelt.Application.Model.pdb" target="lib/netstandard2.0" />
    <file src="bin/*/netstandard2.0/ToolBelt.Application.Contracts.dll" target="lib/netstandard2.0" />
    <file src="bin/*/netstandard2.0/ToolBelt.Application.Contracts.pdb" target="lib/netstandard2.0" />
  </files>
</package>
```

- The project must have a `.gitlab-ci.yml` that contains all the steps to build, run generate nuget and push it to a nuget repository (in my case at Artifactory). Example:

```
#Stages
stages:
  - ci
  - codequality
  - build
  - publish

#Global variables
variables:
  GIT_STRATEGY: $STRATEGY
  BUILD_NUMBER: $CI_PIPELINE_ID

#Jobs
ci:
  image: ocp-golden-images.artifactory.mycompany.eu/gitlab-runner-nuget-dotnet-core:latest
  stage: ci
  script:
    - export VERSION=$(echo $(date +"%Y.%-m%d").$CI_PIPELINE_ID)
    - export NUGET_PACKAGE_FOLDER=nupkgs
    - dotnet build --configuration Release
    - dotnet vstest ./*Tests/bin/Release/**/*Tests.dll
    - mkdir $NUGET_PACKAGE_FOLDER
    - nuget pack ./*NuGet/*.nuspec -Version $VERSION -OutputDirectory $NUGET_PACKAGE_FOLDER -Prop Configuration=Release -NoDefaultExcludes -Verbosity detailed
    - cd $NUGET_PACKAGE_FOLDER
    - dotnet nuget push *.$VERSION.nupkg -s https://artifactory.mycompany.eu/artifactory/api/nuget/MyRepo
```

So those are all the commands required to build a project with a structure like:

```
myApp
-ToolBelt.Application.Nuget
--ToolBelt.Application.Nuget.nuspec
-ToolBelt.Application.Contracts
-ToolBelt.Application.Model
-ToolBelt.Application.Model.UnitTests
```

where the project that contains the nuspec (e.g: `ToolBelt.Application.Nuget`) MUST have a dependency to each project that is required to be included in the package (e.g: `ToolBelt.Application.Contracts` and `ToolBelt.Application.Model`)

Comment: This is great! Would you be willing to share a demo project?

Comment: Sure, here's a demo project of an open source package of mine https://gitlab.com/sunnyatticsoftware/sasw-test-support

Answer (score 2):

> The problem with dotnet pack command is that I cannot reference the
> nuspec file, it is simply ignored.

For `dotnet pack` you should define `<NuspecFile>***.nuspec</NuspecFile>` property in `***.csproj`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#nuspecfile
https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/9788#issuecomment-689151144

Answer (score 0):

You must check build logs for errors. Maybe there are some of its presents.
I tried to create package and used following:
1. Directory structure

```
solution \
   interfaces
       bin
           debug
               netcore2.1
                   interfaces.dll
                   common.dll
                   configuration.dll
           interfaces.nuspec
       interfaces.csproj
       IService.cs
   models
   configuration
```

2. Nuspec content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2012/06/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
        <id>Interfaces</id>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <authors>Interfaces</authors>
        <owners>Interfaces</owners>
        <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
        <description>Package Description</description>
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <file src="netstandard2.0\Common.dll" target="lib\netstandard2.0\Common.dll" />
        <file src="netstandard2.0\Configuration.dll" target="lib\netstandard2.0\Configuration.dll" />
        <file src="netstandard2.0\Interfaces.dll" target="lib\netstandard2.0\Interfaces.dll" />
        <file src="netstandard2.0\Models.dll" target="lib\netstandard2.0\Models.dll" />
    </files>
</package>
```

3. From solution\interfaces folder I run:

```
dotnet pack interfaces.csproj /p:NuspecFile="bin\debug\interfaces.nuspec"
```

And all is fine, nupkg contains all *.dll.
But if something wrong (paths for example) I got errors.

Comment: but what happens if you have more than one csproj? which one do you reference in your `dotnet pack`?
That's why I favour `nuget pack` over `dotnet pack`, because I have multiple csproj and wouldn't know which one to choose.
I have something like this: `nuget pack ./*NuGet/*.nuspec -Version $VERSION -OutputDirectory nupkgs -Prop Configuration=Release -NoDefaultExcludes -Verbosity detailed`

Comment: In that case, you can create a meta project for an only reason to create nuget package. It's some kind of workaround.

Comment: Yep, that's why I prefer to use `nuget` command when I have a nuspec. Because the nuspec "knows" about all the projects within the solution (all the dll), while `dotnet pack` would require workarounds like the one you suggested. But thanks!